# struct 'type cast' error in C?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Suppose I have some struct `DATA` defined. Then I attempt the following code:

```
struct DATA data1, data2;
data2 = (DATA)(*(DATA))&data1);
```

Why do I get error C2440 on 'type cast'?

Comment: @melpomene: Let me google that for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Are you compiling as C or as C++? The "c" tag implies C, but referring to the type `struct DATA` as just `DATA` implies C++.

Answer (score 2):

This part is the problem:

```
(DATA)&data1
```

Here you takes the address of `data1` making into a pointer, type `struct DATA *`. Then you try to cast it to a non-pointer `struct DATA` type which is what the error is probably about. (Hint: Please post complete and unedited error messages in the future.)

You actually don't have to do any casting, or address-of pointer handling or dereferencing at all. Just assign one structure to the other, and the compiler will create code to do the proper copying:

```
data2 = data1;
```

Comment: Warning the type is not `DATA *` but it is `struct DATA *`

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is :

```
struct DATA data1, data2;
data2 = (struct DATA)(*((struct DATA*)&data1));
```

But this is useless... What not doing this :

```
struct DATA data1, data2;
data2 = data1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's illegal to cast to a struct type. The type specified by a cast operator must be either `void` or a scalar type (i.e., an arithmetic or pointer type).

This:

```
data2 = data1;
```

is a much simpler way to do what I *think* you're trying to do (it's hard to tell).